# Continuous Crawls Search

Tags: search

Hope everyone is doing well,
does search Continuous Crawls pick up metadatas?
and also which one is preferred? is it similar do incremental or has some down side?
Regards

Comment: This may has already been answered in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84913/difference-between-continious-crawl-and-incremental-scheduled-crawl by referencing https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2012/09/14/how-can-i-achieve-the-best-freshness-of-search-results-introducing-continuous-crawls-for-sharepoint/

Answer (score 1):

Continuous crawls are 'intelligent' incremental crawls and pick up all of the same data. CC is preferred over scheduling incremental crawls. In addition, I recommend not running any form of full crawl, outside of a few select scenarios (troubleshooting, adding a new managed property in the SSA, though it is preferred to do so at the site level where possible). This is for SharePoint sources.